# How to ask for arbitration if question gets mistakenly downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, unanswered-questions

I asked some totally legitimate questions but got downvoted by some person. My question shows I've done research but existing solutions found don't fit my need. The guy thought the question was too trivial so he downvoted it and posted some answer, which doesn't fit my need either so I edited my question to clarify my need; he then deleted the answer but didn't remove the downvote.

The problem is, the question no longer shows up in 'Unanswered' tab, and thus can't reach to the persons who know the answer.  I am not too frustrated by getting downvoted, but the fact it is no longer visible to other person is very frustrating.  I just wonder what I can do for that? Bounty is an option but since the high cost and uncertainty whether it will still be invisible given the downvote and 'answered' tag in the system, I wonder if there is a better way.

My question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708447/bash-track-status-of-multiple-background-job).

Comment: There's no answer, so it shows up in the unanswered tab... just further down. And you can't know unless you were told that he downvoted it.  What are you trying to do? Dispute the downvote (you can't), or get more vision on the question (bounty or edit)?

Comment: Please don't start discussions here about a single downvote. Also your question certainly can be improved, it's actually unclear what your goal is, you only state that this and that doesn't fit your needs. Make a clear problem statement and explain your actual requirements.

Comment: @Patrice I assume downvote also influence the ranking.  That's what I am concerning here.  Butterfly effect makes it a huge difference between the initial downvote vs upvote, and is there a way to systematically fight against this type of bias?

Comment: @icando There is no such bias. If your question is good, it'll get upvoted by people who see it. There's no bias that "good questions with downvotes only get downvoted". Bad content goes down, good content goes up. Instead of opening your question and positioning yourself as if your question is pristine... ask what you can do to improve it.

Comment: Assuming your assertion is correct, the best place to ask is here.   OTOH, if you are wrong, then the worst place to ask is here.

Comment: If you add a bounty it's going to show up in the bounty tag. There's one in there with a score of -2 but it still shows up on the first page if I sort by "newest".

Comment: Oh and the argument should be made that if someone could provide an answer that you then invalidated with an edit means your question was unclear. If there are limitations in your requirements that means some methods are not appropriate, you should let whoever answers know. Not doing it is actually slightly rude, considering someone is giving his time freely.

Comment: @BSMP, The problem for bounty is, it attracts bad answers. I did bounty several times before, none of them gets the correct answer I need, and someone who came and just gave some random answer got the bounty points.

Comment: That's not what you say in your post. Your post says, *"Bounty is an option but since the high cost and **uncertainty whether it will still be invisible given the downvote** and 'answered'"*. That's why I pointed out that a downvoted bounty would still be visible.

Comment: Now I moved sentences around in the question to make it clear.  Anyway to get it reopened?

Comment: @Patrice, I don't agree with "Bad content goes down, good content goes up."  This is true statistically, but if we drill down to any single post, this no longer holds.  People tends not even open a post with negative votes, therefore there is fewer chance the initial negative votes will get corrected. Also psychologically people is easy to get influenced by other people, so initial negative votes influences decisions from follow-up voters.

Comment: @icando stats or it doesn't happen. Honestly, this is a claim we see often on meta. When asking people to actually prove it (the normal is "show me a good question with downvotes that doesn't get corrected"), the examples fall short... Not saying it isn't there for sure. I've just never seen any kind of proof of this, and no one was ever able to show me good proof of that.  (and yeah... that's how stats work, so I fail to see your point... you will have anomalies here and there, but OVERALL, the system balances itself... like it does here)

Comment: @Patrice, I edited the question and now it is definitely a good and clear question.  If you guys can reopen it and NOT to remove the downvotes, then I am pretty sure you will see the proof the first time in your life that how a -3 downvote won't be corrected automatically.  The problem here is, I usually do a lot of research before posting on SO, so a lot of my questions are difficult to answer. Since only a small set of experts might know the answer and are interested in it, while most people don't know or aren't interested, the SO's voting system is no longer effective.

Comment: You *might* have more luck on [unix.se]. No promises, but they do list "Shell scripting" in their [on-topic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page. You may want to ask if the question is on-topic on their [meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, looks like unix&linux has too little traffic.  In the past, I asked a couple of questions, but none of them got any useful answer.

Answer (score 9):

You can't.

Votes can be used however the voter wishes, so long as there isn't a pattern of abuse (i.e. serial voting patterns).

As to your question, it's certainly getting plenty of attention from the folks here on Meta.   Frankly, I don't understand what the problem with the question is; it seems pretty clear to me, even in the first revision.

Comment: To expand on this point, if it WAS a pattern of abuse, the system will take care of it.